# Why does the result of ssh-keyscan -H contain a header line with the un-hashed server ID?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm attempting to build a global `known_hosts` file for my AWS VPC, and was looking at using `ssh-keyscan` to acquire the fingerprints of new servers as they are created.  The `-H` option seems sensible, as it means you

> do not reveal identifying information should the file's contents be disclosed

Strangely though, the output of that command comes with a helpful header:

```
# 1.2.3.4 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
```

... which seems to rather defeat the point doesn't it?  Obviously I can strip that bit out very easily, but having asked for hashing, I'd expect the output to contain only hashed data.  Is there some logical reason for this, or is it a bug?

Comment: For reference, to ignore the comment: `ssh-keyscan -H -t ecdsa 1.2.3.4 | grep ^[^#]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there some logical reason for this, or is it a bug?

It's not a bug, it is a feature. The line with the comment is written to `stderr` unlike the host keys, therefore it is no problem if you do

```
ssh-keyscan -H -t rsa host > /your/known_hosts
```

The list of hosts will go to your terminal and not into the file.

Example:

```
ssh-keyscan -H -t rsa host 2> /dev/null
```

will show you only the hashed keys and no "comments" with hostnames.

Comment: It's rather odd and annoying that it does this, but piping stderr to `/dev/null`is how I clean its output too.

Comment: @starfry It is quite standard way, writing output to stdout and notes/errors to stderr. Isn't it what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: I was just agreeing with you. I encountered your answer when searching for any other way to suppress the unwanted output in the first place (like a `-q` option) but there isn't one.